Change color of numbered list
Using Beamer in R Markdown (in R Studio, Windows 10), I am trying to change the color of a numbered list (enumerate) to have a custom color. I was successful in doing so for bullet points (itemize).
This post covers the process for itemize, but I can't get it to work for enumerate.
I would prefer to keep using the theme and colortheme if possible.
MRE
---
title: "test"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Berlin
    colortheme: beaver
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \definecolor{berlinred}{rgb}{0.64,0,0}
  - \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=berlinred}
---

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with Numbered List

1. hi
2. hello
3. greetings


Current Output

Desired Output
Similar to current output, but instead of a blue square surrounding the numbers, use the color defined by \definecolor{berlinered}{rgb}{0.64,0,0} in the YAML section above.
Software Versions
I'm guessing the versions are not the problem, but I'm including them for completeness.

Knitr: 1.46
R: 4.3.2
Pandoc: 3.1.7
xcolor: 3.01
MikTex: 24.3


You can change the item projected colour:
---
title: "test"
author: "author"
date: "date"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Berlin
    colortheme: beaver
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \definecolor{berlinred}{rgb}{0.64,0,0}
  - \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=berlinred}
  - \setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=berlinred}
---

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with Numbered List

1. hi
2. hello
3. greetings


